# Program Not Writing List Output Alphabetically to File

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
def typeMovie():
    import os
    os.chdir("/Users/Name/Desktop/Data Sets")

    input_file = open("MoviesTotalEarnings.txt", "r")
    output_file = open("MoviesTotalEarningsType.txt", "w")

    allItems = []

    for line in input_file:
        data = line.split("\t")

        allItems.append(data)

    allItems.sort()

    for data in allItems:
        output_file.write("{}\n".format(data[2]))

    input_file.close()
    output_file.close()

typeMovie()
```

Here's the output:

```
Best Picture
Biggest Gross
Biggest Gross
Best Picture
Sundance
Sundance
Series
Series
Series
Series
Series
Best Picture
Biggest Gross
Sundance
Biggest Gross
Biggest Gross
Sundance
Biggest Gross
Best Picture
Best Picture
Series
Series
Biggest Gross
Series
Sundance
Biggest Gross
Biggest Gross
Sundance
Sundance
Best Picture
Series
Series
Series
Biggest Gross
Series
Series
Series
Biggest Gross
Biggest Gross
Sundance
Sundance
Best Picture
Sundance
Sundance
Best Picture
Best Picture
Best Picture
Biggest Gross
Biggest Gross
TYPE
```

The above output is not the correct output I'm looking for. Obviously, it's not written alphabetically to the output file, and I don't know how to fix it.

The expected output should be along these lines:

```
Best Picture
Best Picture
Best Picture
Biggest Gross
Biggest Gross
Series
Series
Series
Sundance
Sundance
```

Only thing for the above output is that they'll be more instances of these words in the file, but it's just an example.

Here's the actual text file of "MoviesTotalEarnings":

```
NUMBER  MOVIE   TYPE    TOTAL
1   A Beautiful Mind    Best Picture    170.71
2   American Beauty Best Picture    130.06
3   Batman  Biggest Gross   251.19
4   Beverly Hills Cop   Biggest Gross   234.76
5   Chicago Best Picture    170.69
6   Crash   Best Picture    55.33
7   "Departed, The" Best Picture    133.31
8   "Empire Strikes Back, The"  Biggest Gross   290.27
9   ET  Biggest Gross   435.11
10  Forrest Gump    Biggest Gross   329.69
11  Ghost Busters   Biggest Gross   238.63
12  Gladiator   Best Picture    187.68
13  Gods and Monsters   Sundance    6.45
14  "Good Girl, The"    Sundance    14.02
15  Harry Potter 1: Sorcerer's Stone    Series  317.56
16  Harry Potter 2: Chamber of Secrets  Series  261.99
17  Harry Potter 3: Prisoner of Azkeban Series  249.54
18  Harry Potter 4: Goblet of Fire  Series  290.01
19  Harry Potter 5: Order of the Phoenix    Series  292
20  Home Alone  Biggest Gross   285.76
21  In the Company of Men   Sundance    2.88
22  Independence Day    Biggest Gross   306.17
23  Jurassic Park   Biggest Gross   357.07
24  "Last Mimzy, The"   Sundance    21.47
25  "Lion King, The"    Biggest Gross   312.86
26  Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King   Best Picture    377.03
27  Million Dollar Baby Best Picture    100.42
28  Pirates 1: Curse of the Black Pearl Series  305.41
29  Pirates 2: Dead Man's Chest Series  423.32
30  Pirates 3: At World's End   Series  309.4
31  Quinceanera Sundance    1.69
32  Raiders of the Lost Ark Biggest Gross   242.37
33  Return of the Jedi  Biggest Gross   309.21
34  "Road Home, The"    Sundance    1.28
35  Run Lola Run    Sundance    7.27
36  Shakespeare in Love Best Picture    100.32
37  Shrek   Series  267.65
38  Shrek 2 Series  436.72
39  Shrek the Third Series  321.01
40  Spider-Man  Series  403.71
41  Spider-Man 2    Series  373.52
42  Spider-Man 3    Series  336.53
43  Star Wars   Biggest Gross   461
44  Star Wars: Phantom Menace   Biggest Gross   431.09
45  Super Size Me   Sundance    11.53
46  Thirteen    Sundance    4.6
47  Titanic Best Picture    600.79
48  "Upside of Anger, The"  Sundance    18.76
49  You Can Count on Me Sundance    9.18
```

Comment: How does "MoviesTotalEarnings.txt" look like? I ask because `allItems.sort()` is sorting list of lists. Not list of strings.

Comment: I made an answer. Think, you need to specify a key which is going to be used for sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to add key to your sort. Thus to sort for third column, you need

```
 allItems.sort(key=lambda v: v[2])
```

Answer (score 2):

`allItems.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(2))`